# DROP TABLE IF EXISTS under compatibility level 120

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Our production SQL Server are running on version 2014 (12.0.6433.1) and our development SQL Server is version 2019 (15.0.4033.1).

The development database is set to compatibility level 120 to simulate production. A script developed against the dev database failed in production as the syntax was only introduced in SQL Server 2016.

The example below executes in SSMS (18.5) against the development database with compatibility level 120 despite it being introduced SQL Server 2016 in version.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Compatability120_TEST] (ID INT)
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[Compatability120_TEST]
GO
```

Should setting the compatibility level have prevented it working in development?

Comment: No. The purpose of compatibility levels is not to provide a 100% emulation of old versions. There is no previous behaviour for `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` that backwards compatibility needs to be preserved for so it is allowed. This is generally useful as it allows you to use the new syntax in new code. Seems like you need a test pre-production environment that is configured as prod.

Comment: I was just about to say what Martin said, almost verbatim. :P If you want proper version checks, use [database projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/ssdt/project-oriented-offline-database-development); setting the target version to 2016 will check for syntax that is not supported there (and building the project will generate a script that only uses 2016 syntax -- barring some bugs). You can also use LocalDB installs of the proper versions if you need a more solid test.

Comment: Thanks both, We do have a Pre-Production environment which mirrors Production where this was flagged so the question was asked how the error got in there and it came back to the above. We do have a database project but don't use it to generate or build the script but will investigate that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The purpose of compatibility levels is not to provide a 100% emulation of old versions. There is no previous behavior for `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` that backwards compatibility needs to be preserved for so it is allowed. This is generally useful as it allows you to use the new syntax in new code. Seems like you need a test pre-production environment that is configured as prod.

If you want proper version checks, use database projects. Setting the target version to 2016 will check for syntax that is not supported there (and building the project will generate a script that only uses 2016 syntax -- barring some bugs). You can also use LocalDB installs of the proper versions if you need a more solid test.

Comment: With all due respect, this is a copy/paste of comments made by others above. Do you mind at least cutting your sources?

Comment: @BenThul, this is a community wiki answer, not mine, gleaned from comments.  I did not contribute to the content. The sources are the comments on the question but feel free to edit this answer to attribute as you see fit since it belongs to the community.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In the SE mobile app, it does not show up as such (it looks like any other answer to a question). I'll leave my comment here as a testament to my learning (which is in the spirit of the site as a whole).